# NetBeans IDE Постоянно откатывает файлы до даты создания.

Tags: откат, netbeans

Работаешь работаешь, пишешь код.

Начинаешь проверять, и не понимаешь почему не работает, а оказывается что какие-то файлы, из-за чего-то, откатились назад.

Да есть в редакторе кнопка отката, но её не нажимал никогда, а теперь приходится ею пользоваться из-за того что редактор сам берет и откатывает файлы, причем разные файлы, как открытые в окне, так и не открытые.

Тестировать проекты и редактировать код невозможно стало, происходит уже неделю где-то.

Кто сталкивался с такой лабудой? из-за чего происходит этот откат?

Comment: Проверьте локальное время на компе, возможно происходит из-за неправильного времени

Comment: Время нормальное стоит, с этим все гуд.
Просто понять бы из-за чего вся эта канитель

Comment: Удалите к черту весь кэш Netbeans, лежит в `~/.netbeans/7.0/var/cache`

Comment: Папка кэша пуста, в ней обычно ничего у меня и нет.